# How can I add extra information for each term reference?

Tags: nodes, entities, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to create a content type that matches a product. The product can be made of several thing in different percentages:

Eg.

```
material 1:
    material 1.1: 5%
    material 1.2: 0%
    material 1.3: 20%
material 2: 75%
material 3: 0%
material 4:
    material 4.1 0%
    material 4.2 0%
```

I've built the materials hierarchy using taxonomies.
How can I add a parameter to a taxonomy so I can do this?

I've tried using [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection), but the problem I encountered was the inability to work with [Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr)

Comment: make material 1 the vocabulary and then material 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 its terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) module, it is a "lightweight" version of field collection, instead of creating an entity structure with relationships, it covers the simple use cases without creating the entity. It works with Solr.

I think that you must read this: [Field Collection vs Entity Reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/121604/28275)

Comment: Does it work with solr? I posted before this was edited into the question, but now when it is, it would be worth to mention it.

Comment: @Mołot yes it works with solr

Comment: Guys, thank you for your fast answers, I'm gonna mark this as best answer, even though both answers we're very good. Multifield works fine. Another solution proposed by my team leader was adding a term refference for the taxonomy, and a field collection for taxonomy + percentage (hiding the normal term refference, and populating it at node_save hook).

Comment: @TacheRazvan Happy ending ;-) god luck with your project

Answer (score 3):

There are two options:

1. Create own module based on taxonomy. Most flexible, but also most complicated. That's what I would do, if I had time and motivation to play.
2. Use [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) - create a collection of term and percentage fields, and make this collection (not individual fields in it) multivalue. *Warning:* I know of no easy way to make sure your percentages adds up to 100%. I know how to do it easily in custom module.... see point 1.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. The problem I've encountered with field collection, is that the [solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module, does not work with Field collection.

Comment: @TacheRazvan That's why you are generally supposed to tell what you have already tried and why it didn't work for you - if you tried anything, that is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this, gonna edit the question.